# what is the fastest way to get all combinations in a for loop

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization

I want to get all the combination of two `int` element say j and i, both shouldn't be smaller than 3, here'S what I've tried:

```
for (int i =  10; i>=3;i--)
{
   for (int j = 23, j >= 3,j--) 
   {
       std::cout << " the i value " << i 
       << "the j value :" << j << std::endl; // since I'm using those combinations  
                                             // for the rest of my code I wrote 
                                             // this to keep things simple    
   }
}
```

is their anyway to do this without the for-loops ?

Comment: What is it that you're trying to optimize here?

Comment: `<<'\n'` instead of `std::endl` in the loop, should be faster

Comment: @devnull getting all combination with a faster way ! @ billz I don't use std::cout  I just get the combinations !

Comment: Are you looking for a combination in the mathematical meaning of the word?

Comment: As this is not your real code, and you did not describe your real application, how can we potentially help to optimize your code?

Comment: What makes you think this isn't blazingly fast already?

Comment: the only thing that I need to optimize is this part that's why I think it will help. I'm using this combinations in the opencv function cv::findChessboardCorners()

Comment: @Jim it just take to much time !

Comment: How on earth are you going to optimize this particular code snippet? It's not possible. If this is "too slow", look t what you have _inside_ the loops, not at the loop iteration itself.

Comment: No, Engine, I'm sure it doesn't. What's taking time is whatever you're doing inside the loop.

Comment: @Engine This code would be probably optimized by compiler to lines instructions:
`std::cout << " the i value " << 10 << "the j value :" << 23 << std::endl;`
`std::cout << " the i value " << 10 << "the j value :" << 22 << std::endl;` and so on to
`std::cout << " the i value " << 3 << "the j value :" << 3 << std::endl;`

Comment: `cv::findChessboardCorners()` -- Um, taking the cross product of [3..10] and [3..23] is not a good way to find the corners of a chessboard. Perhaps if you were more precise about what you're really trying to achieve ... as it is, this is a classic XY Problem (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the only reasonable variant worth trying would be to pre-calculate
the values, put them into a static array, and use a single index to
access them from there.  This is only practical if the number of values
is reasonably small (as in your example), and even then, it's far from
certain that it will spead things up.  You gain one comparison (because
you have a single loop, rather than nested loops), but that comparison
is only executed in the outer loop, and memory access, especially on a
modern machine, can be expensive.

The first thing you should do is profile your code.  If you're doing
anything significant with the values in the loop, the time it takes for
the loop code itself won't even be measurable.  Don't try to optimize
something that doesn't need it.

Answer (score 4):

This is proper way of doing it.

You can use other loops but the logic always remain the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of integers, you can put them in a vector and use `std::next_permutation' to iterate through the possible permutations

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation

Comment: is it faster using next_permutation ?

Comment: @Engine It'll be slower. Your code is nearly as fast as possible for problem you described.

Comment: @Ari Once the optimizer gets through with it, it is as fast as possible.  Not just nearly.

Answer (score 1):

Your way is doubtless the most readable and easy to maintain way.

There is other tricks of course, but it doesn't necessary make the code run faster.

For example, you may simply use 1 level of loop:

```
//assuming I am getting i [0..5), j [0..7)

for (int x = 0; x < 5*7 ; ++x) {
   cout << "i " << x/7 << " j " << x%7 << endl;
}
```

(a bit like the way using 1-demsion array for multi-dimension array, but it doesn't make the code easier or faster anyway.  Just for fun... :P )

Comment: It'll make code works slower. Operators `/` and `%` are very slow.

Comment: @Ari That depends on the platform.  And the constant values.  (But as a general rule, I would expect it to be slower.  Independently of the cost of each operation, you're doing more operations.)

Comment: lol, yes in fact I am aware of that, that's why I said it is just for fun :P

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the correct way of doing it. There might be some other ways of doing it but those will likely be less readable. If you do choose a different approach then make sure you time it, decreasing the readability of the code without a measurable speedup isn't going to be worth it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some kind of loop. You can optimize it a little bit:

1. Use `++i` `--i` instead of `i++` and `i--`. It is easier operation, because `i++` and `i--` returns new value, instead of old.
2. If you want to iterate through two dimension array and order of iteration doesn't matter it's better to iterate first through `j` and then through `i`:

   ```
   for(int j = 0; j < MAXJ; ++j){
       for(int i = 0; i < MAXI; ++i){
           do_sth_with(arr[i][j]);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Don't use `std:endl` if you need just to write new line. `std:endl` forces flush on `stdout` so its slower than `"\n"`.

Comment: Re 1: it makes absolutely no difference.  (I've measured.)  Re 2: I've not measured but unless you're using the values as indices into a large matrix (in which case locality could be an issue), it shouldn't matter.  Re 3: He said that the output to `std::cout` was just an example, so the choice between `'\n'` and `std::endl` is irrelevant (which is usually the case).

Comment: @JamesKanze 1: depending on system and so on it could make difference. Especially if it works on same strange environment (i.e. old/slow cpu). 2: for few MB large arrays it would make difference, tested on home PC.

Comment: Re 1: No, it doesn't make a difference.  Even on an old, slow CPU.  It didn't make a difference on a PDP-11, for example, even though there was a machine instruction for post-incrementation, but not for pre-incrementation.  Both generate exactly the same machine code.  As for 2: he didn't say what he was using his values for.  For relatively large matrices, it probably will make a difference on a modern machine.  He doesn't say what he is doing with the values, however, and the values he's using aren't very large.